# C++11 regex ranges understanding

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, range, match

I'm trying to write a regex that will match particular symbols and ranges of symbols in ascii-table. That regex should be quite complex but I failed to create it at once and so I decided to make a much simpler regex first but even this time I failed. So I ask about this simple one regex.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
    std::string s ("$");
    std::smatch m;

    std::regex e ("([\\x21\\x23-\\x25]+)");

    std::regex_search (s,m,e);

    for (int i = 1; i < m.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << m[i] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here the ascii-codes used in the regex:

```
Decimal  Octal  Hex   Binary          Value
033      041    021   00100001        !    (exclamation mark)

035      043    023   00100011        #    (number sign)
036      044    024   00100100        $    (dollar sign)
037      045    025   00100101        %    (percent)
```

So in my code example I try to get '$' matched but the regex fails: I get empty match. However, if I use

```
std::regex e ("([\\x23-\\x25]+)");      //or
std::regex e ("([\\x23-\\x25\\x21]+)"); //or
std::regex e ("([\\x21\\x24-\\x25]+)"); //or
std::regex e ("([\\x21\\x23-\\x24]+)");
```

the '$' is matched properly and I get non-empty match result.

So I really fail to understand the logic of all this. Could you please give me a hint what's the problem because as I know the order of the ranges (for example, *a-z*) and single symbols (for example, *_*) in regex groups *[ ]* is not relevant?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce the problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11f0b37c9ea5a007).

Comment: @Muscampester, you can try it here http://cpp.sh/. The problem is reproduced.

Comment: So then the problem is with `cpp.sh`. It also works on [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/367665a8dae99e9b), and VS2015.

Comment: @Muscampester, for g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2 it also does not work.

Comment: The regex also seems fine if I check [here](https://regex101.com/r/n1capo/2).

Comment: Which version of g++? My point is that it might be a compiler bug and the solution would be to use a newer version. The question might be updated to  ask why the compiler of that version is not working.

Comment: @Muscampester, but it does not work on cpp.sh and for g++. I think the both are quite important and reliable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132019/discussion-between-mus-campester-and-jenyakh).

Comment: @JenyaKh I'm getting success matches for *all* your posted expressions (to '$'). Double check your g++ version as Mus campester suggests.

Comment: @kabanus, so this g++ 4.9.2 is just bugged?

Comment: I'm now guessing there is implementation defined behavior involved somewhere (internal character representation?), but I'm not sure.

Comment: I found 2 bugs in 4.9.2, which is the first implementation of regex, but not exactly this. My suggestion instead of spending tons of time on this updating and checking for different results.

Comment: @kabanus, thank you, I will update. How do you think, does it make sense to file a bug or this is not usually done for such old versions?

Comment: I can tell you I try to impart a 'user is a loser' attitude to my team - meaning minimum effort for bug fixes. Your version is way to old I think for it get much attention (beyond the generic update response), though your consideration is admirable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
std::regex e ("([!#-%]+)");
```

Comment: I think he needs many more characters, the example is just for reference.

Comment: @kabanus, not "he". But you are right, the regex needed will contain quite more ascii-symbols.

Comment: @JenyaKh my bad, "it" :P. Sorry, I usually remember to s/he.

Comment: @JenyaKh you're right use can use `-` anywhere (and multiple times) in the regex. Except for the first character. Put it there to match `-`

Comment: @PaulEvans, thank you for the answer but "([!#-%])" also does not work (I've tried before). By the way, "([!#$#]+)" works but it's also strange.

Comment: @JenyaKh sorry missed the `+`. Edited accordingly

Comment: @PaulEvans, no, indeed you can check that  std::regex e ("([!#-%]+)"); also does not work. :( Because, generally, it's the same as "([\\x21\\x23-\\x25]+)" by the way.